# Cassandra warn - internal client ping failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax

What does this warning means in Cassandra/Datastax?

```
 WARN  [RMI TCP Connection(2700)-127.0.0.1] 2019-02-22 13:06:12,640  NoSpamLogger.java:97 - internal client ping failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't exist in Cassandra so likely something thats DSE specific. It being from the RMI TCP Connection thread means its from an external tool or app that is calling a JMX endpoint. Probably an agent (do you run opscenter?) or performance service kinda thing so most likely its ignorable. It might be worth opening a ticket with DataStax though.

Comment: Thanks, Will check with Datastax. We do run Opscenter.